# wordpress: anchor tag in php echoes an <a> tag without URl in href

Tags: php, html, wordpress

may someone explain me why this code:

```
echo '<a href="'.$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url().'" id="header_cart"><i class="'. $show_cart .'"></i><span>'. $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count .'</span></a>';
```

echoes this in HTML:

```
<a id="header_cart" href=""><i class="icon-basket"></i><span>1</span></a>
```

i mean, why the href attribute is empty but if i delete the id attribute it works normally?

Comment: `id and href` are different things.

Comment: i know but if i delete the id attribute the URL in href attribute appears magically :P

Comment: Are you sure `$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url()` actually returns something? Try saving it to a variable and echo just that variable to check.

Comment: i tryed adding an html comment wich contains the $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() variable and it worked...so the variable returns the right url. i'm going mad

Comment: There could be a filter that is modifying the output based on the element's id attribute.  Since the variable is valid and removing that ID works that's about all I can think of.